# How can I get a container with position:relative having content with position:absolute inside to flow in-line with text in a paragraph or div?

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to stack icons from the Google Material Symbols font inside a paragraph or div to achieve an in-fill colour effect.

I am able to get text before the stacked icons to appear correctly in-line but any text after the icons does not appear correctly in line and is obscured by the stack.

Here is the current code:

**CSS:**

```
<style>

span.icon-stack {
  position: relative;
}

span.icon-stack span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>Prefix
    
<span class="icon-stack">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined font-variation-filled" style="color:lightgreen">circle</span>  
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">circle</span>
</span>

Suffix</p>
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyyT9.png)

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htXxn.png)

The fact that I am trying to achieve this effect using the Google Material Symbols typeface is not really relevant, this could be any typeface; hence I have omitted the css which imports that font and achieves the desired FILL axis option.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this please?  I have experimented with the display and position properties of the container and the stacked icons but nothing has enabled me to achieve the desired effect.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at not absolutely-positioning the first element within the stack, so that it takes up space in the layout flow, but then have other elements be absolutely-positioned.

```css
span.icon-stack {
  position: relative;
}

span.icon-stack span:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.font-variation-filled {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:FILL@0..1" rel="stylesheet" />

<p>Prefix
    
<span class="icon-stack">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined font-variation-filled" style="color:lightgreen">circle</span>  
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">circle</span>
</span>

Suffix</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very much appreciated, I note that the icon is now raised within the paragraph.I have tried setting top:0 against the declaration span.icon-stack span:not(:first-child) but the background coloured icon is then still shifted.  The top property has no effect because the position is static.  Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: You could try setting a `vertical-align` property in the `span.icon-stack` rule.

Comment: Ok I have managed to achieve something slightly better by adding an initial icon to the stack (so three in total) and then hide it using span.icon-stack span:first-child) { visibility:hidden }.

This seems overkill though, do you have a slicker suggestion that I may have overlooked?

Comment: Since the wrapping icon-stack element is already relative you can easily add an offset e.g via `bottom:-0.2em)`. See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/YzJqamr). Vertical align can also introduce additional margins - so better use top/bottom or even a transform/translate.

Comment: @herrstrietzel, thanks for your suggestions, I am still suffering slight alignment issues integrating your proposal but have managed to implement the proposed solution with display:flex on the containing paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
<style>

p.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
}

span.icon-stack {
  position: relative;
}

span.icon-stack span:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="d-flex">Prefix
    
<span class="icon-stack">
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined font-variation-filled" style="color:lightgreen">circle</span>    
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">circle</span>
</span>

Suffix

</p>
```